# Determining state type in context with typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-context

In my project where I calculate the bmi, I want to keep the results as an array in a state and keep them locally.

```
export type BmiContextState = {
    weight: number | undefined;
    height:number | undefined;
    open:boolean|undefined;
    alert:boolean|undefined;
    results:resultState;
    handleWeight(event: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>): void;
    handleHeight(event: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>): void;
    openModal(event: React.MouseEvent<HTMLButtonElement, MouseEvent>):void;
    openAlert(event: React.MouseEvent<HTMLButtonElement, MouseEvent>):void;
    calculate:(weight:number,height:number)=>number;
    bmi:(bmi:number)=>string;

  };

export interface resultState {
    results:{
      bmi:number,
      bmiResult:string,
    }
}
```

I defined a type called resultstate and I want my objects in it. I defined the types like this.

```
const contextDefaultValues: BmiContextState = {
  weight: 0,
  height: 0,
  result: (0,"obesite")[],
  open: false,
  alert: false,
  handleWeight() {},
  handleHeight() {},
  openModal() {},
  openAlert() {},
  calculate: (weight, height) => 0,
  bmi: (bmi) => "",
};
```

The result part gives an error, how should I define it?

Comment: Put `playground` link to execute typescript code

Comment: what is the playground

Comment: It's an online editor for typescript.

Answer (score 1):

You have to change `result` to `results` and then you can initialize it as below:

```
results: {results:{bmi:0,bmiResult: 'hello'}}
```

See [Working Sample](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=23&ssc=49&pln=23&pc=3#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBDAnmYcBCBbAlgYQgOxlBgGUYBDIuAXjgG8AoOZuAd2CwHMALGALjj4ArhgBGwKHAA%20cIfgAmwAGZZ8weQG4mLbhx79hYidNkLlq9VpZwIKfH1EQIAG2Dl8UuYpVrN25uSusA5Oru6eZj6W-nBQwADOQs4w8XxxiclklMBWLADGgXlJ2XwAFOxcvHyG4lAANLqVBiK1AJTUAHw1ErnMothl-VjVLRLtHfEwUKqcWtoAvnOgkLBwqkRQSuR5qOlJpBRUjNZ7yanH1nBDI0b1MX3YAEoJ%203yT0-icdTHzDL8MDDyBEmcCBhGIABFlOR9gA1QJCBICTC4AhEEAHbI0ejaCr6AQABm%20zEa%20LgRO0pxSAjoVPO1yJQ2eGX4cAA5LpnM4IGz5vNiTY7AIts54sABYEJKyRWKBQVnEVnCU4OU9Lw6nBSbxWjQOuSBdcVUMdZ04AAiM3fRZAA)

Comment: this time it gives an error while sending result inside the provider.
it says ;  Type '{ open: boolean | undefined; alert: boolean | undefined; weight: number; height: number; result: resultState; handleWeight: (event: any) => void; handleHeight: (event: any) => void; openModal: (event: any) => void; openAlert: (event: any) => void; calculate: (weight: number,
height: number) => number; bmi: (bmi: num...' is not assignable to type 'BmiContextState'.
  Object literal may only specify known properties, but 'result' does not exist in type 'BmiContextState'. Did you mean to write 'results'?ts

Comment: Please write your code in [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play) and then add that `url` in  comment to debug that.

Comment: There are lots of dependency for your code. Is it possible to remove the dependency (react and ..)? I think the main problem is in typescript